# Accessing variables having integer inside the name

Tags: bash, awk, sh

I am trying to do some operations (like adding columns) with two sets of files (some large numbers of files). The two sets are identical in number of files as well as the data format inside the files.

```
  set1:          set2:
  fileA          fileX
  fileB          fileY
  fileC          fileZ


  cat fileA
  1
  2
  cat fileX
  5
  6
```

I am trying to add the columns of them

```
 paste fileA fileX > tmpA
 awk '{print $1+$2}' tmpA > output1

 paste fileB fileY > tmpB
 awk '{print $1+$2}' tmpB > output2
```

I want to do this operation with a `for` loop.
Since the files are not identified with any numeric in the file name,
what I am trying to do is the following:

```
f1=dir1/fileA
f2=dir1/fileB
f3=dir1/fileC

g1=dir2/fileX
g2=dir2/fileY
g3=dir2/fileZ

for i in `seq 1 3`
do
paste $f$i $g$i > tmp
awk '{print $1+$2}' tmp > output$i
rm tmp
done
```

**My question: is there any way I can identify `$f$i` as `$f1,$f2,$f3` variables assigned to files?**

Many thanks.

Comment: You could use [indirect references](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) (the link isn't great, you should use the `${!var}` notation it barely mentions), but if I were you I'd use two arrays instead

Comment: A better link: [BashFAQ/006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006). Also, don't use `seq`, use C-style `for` loops: `for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using two arrays you'll iterate over concurrently :

```
f_files=(dir1/fileA dir1/fileB dir1/fileC) # or shorter :  =(dir1/file{A,B,C})
g_files=(dir2/fileX dir2/fileY dir2/fileZ) # or shorter :  =(dir2/file{X,Y,Z})

for ((i=0; i<${#f_files[@]}; i++)); do
    paste ${f_file[$i]} ${g_files[$i]} > tmp
    awk '{print $1+$2}' tmp > output$i
    rm tmp
done
```

I've based the number of iterations on the length of the `f_files` array, but note that it starts from 0 since arrays are indexed from 0, which impacts the output file names. That could obviously be fixed by a bit of arithmetics if need be.

I suggest also removing the intermediary `tmp` file (`paste ${f_file[$i]} ${g_files[$i]} | awk ...`) or at least only deleting it once the loop is over since `>` overwrite the file's content.

Comment: This is indeed elegant solution to the problem. I never thought of using arrays for such cases. In the above code however the last iteration does not escape and probably `$(( ${#f_files[@]} - 1 ))` kind of thing is needed. Many thanks for the links also.

Comment: is there any way to access the strings `A,B,C` from `(dir1/file{A,B,C})`?

Comment: @Boogeyman You're right about the iteration, I was off by one, I've updated the answer. The `{A,B,C}` is expanded on the line it's used, and I don't see a way to retrieve it short of string manipulation (e.g. `${var##prefix_to_remove}`)

Comment: Don't use `seq`, use C-style `for` loops: `for ((i=1; i<=3; i++))`

Comment: @Aaron, I wanted to ask `dir1/file{A,B,C}` whether A, B, C could also be numbers, special characters eg. `0.500`

Comment: @Boogeyman Yes, it's just an enumeration of strings. You can use ranges of integers or single characters too such as `{A..C}` or `{1..9..2}`(odd digits). Check [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).

Answer (score 1):

I really like @Aaron answer.
I just suggest to include the `paste` command into the `awk` command.
So that it is eventually look like:

```
f_files=(dir1/fileA dir1/fileB dir1/fileC) # or shorter :  =(dir1/file{A,B,C})
g_files=(dir2/fileX dir2/fileY dir2/fileZ) # or shorter :  =(dir2/file{X,Y,Z})

for i in $(seq 0 ${#f_files[@]}); do
    awk 'NR==FNR{inp1[NR]=$1; next;} {print($1+inp1[FNR])}' "${f_files[i]}" "${g_files[i]}" > output$i
done
```

I added quotes around `"${f_files[i]}"` and `"${g_files[i]}"`, just in case file name had any whitespaces.